# Expectation and Variance of a Ratio

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $(Y_i,X_i)_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d random variables and let $A$ be a set such that $P(X \in A) > 0$

The problem is to calculate the Expectation and the Variance of the expression $$ T =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}  $$
Here's my work which I think is wrong at some step but I cant make out which. We condition on the random vector $Z=(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ where $Z_i = \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)$ $$ E \bigg(  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}    \bigg | Z) = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)} \sum_{i=1}^n E[Y_i|Z] \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)     $$
But since they are i.i.d $E[Y_i|Z]=E[Y_i|Z_i]= E[Y|X \in A] \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A) + E[Y|X \in A^c] \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A^c)   $

It follows that $$ E \bigg(  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_i \in A)}    \bigg | Z) = E[Y |X \in A]   $$
But this seems strange since the right hand side is a constant and does not depend on $Z$

I was going to compute the variance using the law of total variance but since the above is a constant this would imply that Var$(E[T|Z]) = 0$ and all the variance would be coming from $E(Var(T|Z))$.

Assuming this is true I'm getting that $$ Var(T|Z) = \frac{Var(Y|X \in A)}{\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_j \in A)}  $$

My results dont seem like they are right and unfortunately I cant spot the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the expected value is right. Think about it like this: $T$ is the sample mean of the $Y_i$, only restricted to where $Z_i=1.$ Doesn't it make sense that the conditional expected value of this would just be $E(Y|Z=1)$ and thus not depend on how the $Z$'s actually realize?

The variance of the sample mean is just $\mathrm{Var}(Y)/n$ so again, the fact that you got $\mathrm{Var}(Y|Z=1)$ divided by the realized sample size for the conditional variance given $Z$ also makes intuitive sense to me (although that doesn't mean it's right and I haven't gone through the calculation.)